# Unit test with Mockito for long and convoluted methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

Using Mockito for testing, I can easily unit tests this method:

```
public void doTheDog() {

    // Some code

    extObj.executeDog();
}
```

I will simply verify that executeDog() has been called:

```
verify(extObj).executeDog();
```

However when I have a very long and convoluted method, this is not always as easy.

```
public void doTheDog() {

    // Very long code

    extObj.bark();

    // Very long code

    extObj.walk();
}
```

The above method will still behave as a dog, even if I remove bark(). So it doesn't make much sense to test for it:

```
verify(extObj).bark();
```

After mocking, there isn't something that really tells me if the code works fine!!!

End of the story. Now I have to write unit tests for code that is for the most like the long-and-convoluted code above. What can I do to write good unit tests anyway with mocking?

Comment: Are bark, walk, and executeDog private methods? If so you should not verify them. Rather you should verify the post condition of the doTheDog method. Only if the legs and mouth of the dog are seperate components you can mock and verify that they've been invocated.

Comment: Bark, walk etc. are not private. They belong to another object.

Comment: Are the execution of bark and walk under certain circumstances part of the post condition of doTheDog? If yes, then it would be wise write tests that covers the code that invokes them. However you may wish to be pragmatic and only cover the most important scenarios. After that, perhaps refactor the convoluted code. If not, why bother invoking them?

Comment: I think you should refactor "Very long code" to make it easily testable and shouldn't try to avoid refactoring with nasty things.

Answer (score 1):

As mpkorstanje began in the comments, a good unit test should verify that the behavior of a given unit matches the spec as tightly and concisely as possible.

It sounds like part of the problem here is that your spec isn't clearly defined: `dog.bark()` is important enough to happen, but not important enough to be specified or tested. If you feel the method is long and convoluted, the best solution is to *refactor the method into small, clear, testable pieces* and then test those individually. This will likely also make them easier to work with in your actual production systems.

All that said, Mockito is designed for flexible tests, as compared to replay-based mocking systems: It is entirely your choice whether to `verify(dog).bark()`, or you can choose whether or not exact quantity `atLeastOnce()` or order (see InOrder) matters. Generally speaking, shoot to specify as little as possible, so that your tests will pass for any working implementation or change in your actual system.